# Default value not working for reflected model in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've 2 different flask app sharing the same database using SqlAlchemy reflection. Everything working fine except column like these:

`created_on = Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)`

`updated_on = Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)`

aren't not getting default value on insert or update.

Do I need to overwrite those columns from the reflected model?

Comment: And overriding defaults of reflected columns is covered in ["Override default in sqlalchemy reflected tables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939893/override-default-in-sqlalchemy-reflected-tables)

Comment: @IljaEverilä I think you've missed the point that this question isn't about how to overwrite column from a reflected model.

Comment: I did not miss that, and the duplicate target used is not about overriding columns. The previous *comment* is directed at your final question "Do I need to overwrite those columns from the reflected model?", were you to take that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a normal limitation of reflection. Because `default` is a client/app side operation where the default value is generated by the app code.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#limitations-of-reflection
I've replaced `default` with `server_default` to fix it. Had to sacrifice the python DateTime format by the way.