# sqlalchemy '(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

We're trying to migrate a large table (bigger than local memory space) from a postgresql database to a local sqlite3 database using sqlalchemy, but we're getting a syntax error when trying to create the table in the sqlite3 database. Reading through the other posts, the recommended fixes don't seem to apply to this error. Is there some usage detail we're missing here?

```py
# reflect table from remote postgresql database
read_engine = create_engine('postgresql://dbusername:dbuserpassword@server/dbname')

meta = MetaData()
raw = Table('db_table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=read_engine)

# write table to local sqlite3 database
write_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db_local.sqlite3')

table.create(write_engine)
```

This is the error we get:

```py
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE db_table (
    id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('db_table_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL, 
    created_at TIMESTAMP, 
    updated_at TIMESTAMP, 
    data TEXT, 
    device_key TEXT, 
    format TEXT, 
    uuid TEXT, 
    CONSTRAINT db_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

]
```

Comment: I suppose SQLite cannot parse `nextval(` because it does not support sequences. You can likely adapt the table schema before doing `table.create()`; adapting a Postgres schema to SQLite is possible in many cases.

Comment: Thanks @9000 . I found the docs on overridding the reflected columns https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html and that worked!

Comment: Curious, why would you migrate data larger than memory can hold from an enterprise server RDBMS, Postgres, to a file-level (non-server) RDBMS, SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that SQLite doesn't support `DEFAULT nextval(...)` -- `nextval()` is a Postgres-specific function that isn't part of the SQLite database.

You'll need to re-write the `CREATE TABLE` statement to use `AUTOINCREMENT`, I believe.

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee

Comment: Makes sense, but SqlAlchemy is creating the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  I did find info about overriding reflected columns [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939893/override-default-in-sqlalchemy-reflected-tables) and added 'Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)' to the `raw = Table()` statement and that worked.